# Leaflet markers: PNG or base64 images?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

What is the recommandation to display a large amount of markers (around 100) on a leaflet Map? Is it better to display markers using a PNG image or a base64 image for the marker icon?

I didn't find anything in the leaflet Doc:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Comment: Base64 is not an image format, it's an encoding *for an image format*.

Comment: Yes that's right, but both solutions are available, so i would like to select the good one

Comment: "Good" is hugely subjective. Try both and see what works best for your particular situation. With something like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) involved this is often a moot point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wondering what makes a difference between using an external image file for your Leaflet Marker icons, and an inlined base64 encoded image.

When using a separate file, browsers are optimized to cache the data.

When your image data is inlined, it might prevent such optimisation, and we can see browser performance degrading. See [Leaflet issue #4968](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968#issuecomment-322422045) performance analysis:

> When loading *a lot* of markers (1000, in my case), the performance is noticably worse for base64 inlined images.
>
> [...] for some reason the layer composition is delayed when using inlined images, which makes the whole load take roughly a second longer.
>
> For casual use, this probably doesn't matter, but if you use a lot of markers, this might be relevant.

Note that as soon as you try displaying more than a few hundred Markers anyway, you should consider using clustering or single canvas-based Markers / icons.

Comment: Just curious: how many is "a few hundred" ? Two hundred or a thousand hundred ? :S

Comment: In this case I was meaning between 3 and 10 hundred. See also https://law.marquette.edu/facultyblog/2014/07/commonly-confused-words-a-couple-a-few-some-several-or-many/comment-page-1/